# How do you have two form fields using flex that occupy 33% of the row?

Tags: angular, forms, css, flexbox

I have a **form** and it has **three columns**.

I'm using **flex to achieve a dynamic width** for each **form element**.

I've run into an issue where **I have two form fields that should fit into 1/3 of the view.**

This is simple with one form field because you add:
 `flex=33`

With **2 fields**, you can't add `flex=16.5`. For `16` **it's too wide**, and `15` **it's too thin.**

**What is the technique for getting two form fields to occupy one third of the view using `flex`?**

```
<div class="flex-100">
  <div class="flex-16">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="flex-16">CONTENT</div>
</div>

.flex-100 {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-16 {
    flex: 1 1 16%;
    max-width: 16%;
    max-height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[image: layout]

**I've got it** =>
The issue is that `flex` is actually from a CSS framework and there are no flex classes in between decimals e.g. `16.5%`.

I can add a custom class that overrides the flex-16 with the following rules:

```
flex: 1 1 16.5%;
max-width: 16.5%;
```

Comment: if each children are to be the same size, use flex:1; else , provide your HTML and CSS to have efficient help.

Comment: You can also use boostrap if this is  what your code looks alike https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eLzaKa where it uses a proper value of 16.666667%

Answer (score 1):

When you set `flex=X` you're actually setting the `flex-grow` attribute. This governs how the flexbox should distribute any available space. In your instance, you do not want them to grow at all, but rather be *exactly* 33%.

To do this, you can set the `flex-basis` attribute. This defines how much space the item should take up *before* calculating available space.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}

.item1 {
  flex-basis: 33%;
  background: green;
}

.item2 {
  flex-basis: 33%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```